# Unity Enum in Function as Parameter Error

Tags: c#, enums

I've wanted to create a function with an enum at the parameters so I just can go in unity and change the value easily, but it gives me an error and I don't know why. I'm really new in programming so pls dont judge me to hard :D

```
void TestFunction(enum TestEnum { name1, name2, name3}) 
{
}
```

Comment: You are mixing a function declaration with an enum declaration. That is not allowed in C#

Comment: declare enum outside method declaration and use it like : ``void TestFunction(TestEnum testEnum){}``

Comment: You can't define a type in a method argument (regardless of it being an enum or not).

Comment: What do you mean by *"so I just can go in unity and change the value easily"*? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RufusL I want to change the value of the variable in unity with a dropdown menu how do i do that?

Comment: 1. Create the enum. 2. Create a class field of the enum's type. 3. Populate a drop-down with all the enum values. 4. In the "selection changed" event of the combo box, change the field value to the combo box selected item value. Give it a shot and come back if you get stuck on something specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare an enum inside a function you have to first declare the enum like this

```
enum TestEnum {
    name1,
    name2,
    name3
}
```

And then you can use it as a parameter

```
void TestFunction(TestEnum testEnum) {
    // Do Something
}
```